# sub-subdomains constrained routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

Currently I have a route like so:

```
constraints(:subdomain => 'api') do
  ...blah blah...
end
```

that works just fine for `api.domain.com` which we will use on production. However on our staging server `api.project.mycompany.com` this doesnt work so great.

My question is: is there a way to make this work with both the subdomain and the sub-subdomain?
If not, then how do I make it work with just the sub-subdomain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ha was just looking through unanswered questions and only just saw the date on this! Obviously jumped back a bit too far in time hehe  Oh well might be helpful to someone else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex instead of a string:

```
constraints(:subdomain => /^api(\.project)?$/) do
  ...blah blah...
end
```

Comment: appreciate the follow up!